# Is there a way to make a game using lwjgl work on android?

Tags: java, android, lwjgl

I'm working on a platformer and I'd like to make an android version. Do I need to rewrite everything for android, or can I use something to make the lwjgl code work with android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I believe you're going to have to [do some work to port it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4596700/1971309):

> One of LWJGL's main features is its OpenGL support. Android natively
>   supports OpenGL ES so there's basically no need for LWJGL. As for the
>   rest of LWJGL, it doesn't apply on the Android platform anyway - for
>   example there is obviously no mouse to an Android device - so I don't
>   see a direct LWJGL port ever being developed.
>
> Check out the Android [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html), especially the [android.opengl package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/package-summary.html),
>   for a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

There is a port:

[image: There is a port]
<sub>(image from the `android-test` repo linked below)</sub>

With LWJGL 3, there is now [support for Android](https://github.com/LWJGL/android-test).

The linked repo has the setup instructions and the demo, the actual code is in the LWJGL3 repo under [the Android branch](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/tree/android).

I've been using it for a while now, and this library has a bunch of useful features that aren't just connected to OpenGLES, OpenAL, OpenVR and Vulkan, but it also has a lot of utilities for things like 3D model loading, layouts, dialogs, fonts and a lot more. Meaning the Android port of LWJGL is a considerable add-on to the current OpenGL ES support.